# Recover data from corrupted dmg

Tags: command-line, data-recovery, dmg-image

I had a simular problem as in the asked question (see link)
[Tools/tips to recover data from a corrupt DMG disk image?](https://superuser.com/questions/14800/tools-tips-to-recover-data-from-a-corrupt-dmg-disk-image/17404#17404?newreg=99dfb02edaf740e4bf162786e0c87992)

Really want to try nworkers solution to this problem but before I do something stupid
I'm not really experienced with terminal code.

How does this command work?
    hdiutil convert  -format UDTO -o

Where does the file have to be? User Home folder?
Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can drag the .dmg to Terminal at the appropriate point in typing the command & it will set the name & path for you.

You can essentially do the same for the output, but change the name.

In essence... Type or copy/paste...
hdiutil convert (then drag dmg here, then type the next bit) -format UDTO -o (drag it again, then backspace a bit & change the name)

Clumsy, but effective.