# Unable to open DMG files - "Corrupt Image"

Tags: macos, mac, data-recovery, macbook, dmg-image

I created a DMG file using Disk utility in Recovery Mode (File -> New Image -> Image from Folder).

[image: Corrupt Image dmg]

I tried all the possible options from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/14800/tools-tips-to-recover-data-from-a-corrupt-dmg-disk-image/):

- extracting DMG using 7Zip - not working
- converting it to another format like ISO - not converting
- opening DMG using Disk Drill - not opening
- opening DMG using Data Rescue - not opening

Is there any way to extract the data from the corrupted DMG file?

Comment: Do you have any idea what might've happened to it? What all has happened to it between when you created it and now?

Comment: @GordonDavisson when i created image, Macbook display "Operation Successfully", that time i not got any error or any warning message.
I created saveral .dmg files like this, small files are opening without any issue, but Big size (Approx more than 2 GB) file is not opening.

Comment: Does that happen if you create and open the file when you [Start up in safe mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25617?locale=en_US) ?

Comment: @harrymc yes, if i try to open file in safe mode, it is display above message

Comment: Try using Disk Utility by dragging the damaged DMG file onto its window, click the file and select “Repair Disk” in the First Aid tab. You could also try the free utility [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/), recommended in such cases.

Comment: Hi @harrymc, I already tried it early and I also mentioned it in question. But unfortunately, I was not able to recover that file.

Comment: The DMG might be too damaged.

Comment: @harrymc I don't know why apple system generated corrupt dmg file because small files are open without any issue but large file gives an error message, and interestingly, I generated all files the same way.

Comment: How much large? Don't you have a reason-code associated with the error? Try also temporarily to disable checksum verification by the command `defaults write com.apple.frameworks.diskimages skip-verify -bool true` (undo if it doesn't help).

Comment: It's approx. more than 3 GB file. Let me try to use this command

Comment: I tried the skip-verify command, but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's then not a checksum problem. If size matters, then this relates probably to your method of creating the DMG.

Answer (score 0):

Found this online.
Here is the link: [How to repair a corrupted sparse bundle/image or dmg file](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TggCS8q5yGE)

Here are the commands:

```
hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck -readwrite /volumes/"name of your image"

fsck_hfs -drfy /dev/diskxsx  (x is your disk number)

hdiutil detach /dev/diskxsx  (x is your disk number)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I tried first command but it gives this error "hdiutil: attach failed - Operation not permitted"

Comment: Use the term `sudo` before the command in order to elevate permissions

Comment: 'sudo' not working

Comment: It should be `hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck -readwrite <path to image>`, i.e. `hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck -readwrite ~/Downloads/image.dmg`. The `/Volumes` (note not `/volumes`) is a total red herring. Also the error in the video is different "no mountable file systems", which is not the same issue as the OP has. It just goes to show that you shouldn't copy information from a youtube video without actually testing the commands....